# What's the difference between Synchronized and Lock in my example?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I wrote a simple code to mock concurrency using `Lock` and `synchronized`.

Source code is as follows:

**Task class** includes a method named `doSomething()` to print the thread name and executing elapsed time.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Task {
    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Thread Name
        sb.append("Thread Name: ").append(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        //Timestamp  for the executing
        sb.append(", elaspsed time: ").append(Calendar.getInstance().get(13)).append(" s ");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

**TaskWithLock** class

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TaskWithLock extends Task implements Runnable {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            doSomething();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}
```

**TaskWithSync** class

```
public class TaskWithSync extends Task implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized ("A") {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main** class

```
public class Main {
    public static void runableTasks(Class<? extends Runnable> clz)
            throws Exception {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        System.out.printf("<-- Start executing %s Task --> \n",
                clz.getSimpleName());

        // Start 3 threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            service.submit(clz.newInstance());
        }

        // Wait for some time, and then close the executor
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        System.out
                .printf("<-- %s Tasks is complet --> \n", clz.getSimpleName());
        service.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Execute tasks with Lock
        runableTasks(TaskWithLock.class);

        //Execute tasks with Synchronized 
        //runableTasks(TaskWithSync.class);
    }
}
```

First time, executing tasks with Synchronized by calling method **runableTasks(TaskWithSync.class);**

```
<-- Start executing TaskWithSync Task --> 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-1, elaspsed time: 28 s 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-3, elaspsed time: 30 s 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-2, elaspsed time: 32 s 
<-- TaskWithSync Tasks is complet -->
```

Second time, executing tasks with Lock by calling method **runableTasks(TaskWithLock.class);**

```
<-- Start executing TaskWithLock Task --> 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-3, elaspsed time: 23 s 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-2, elaspsed time: 23 s 
Thread Name: pool-1-thread-1, elaspsed time: 23 s 
<-- TaskWithLock Tasks is complet -->
```

With the above example using `Lock` and `synchronized` to run the tasks, I have some questions here:

**Q1:** The timestamp in the synchronized example, it reflects the mutex between 3 Threads. But why is the elapsed time in Lock example the same? I don't know why.

**Q2:** What's the difference between `synchronized` and `Lock` in my example?

Please help me out with these 2 questions.

Comment: `private final Lock lock` should be `static` or each thread has it's own lock which makes the lock essentially useless. Also `.lock()` before `try {` or the `finally` part would try to unlock a lock that is not locked (in case `.lock()` throws an exception)

Comment: @zapl By making the lock static, invoking the method on any instance, would block all other method invocations as well, regardless if they are invoked on different object instances. This is certainly not an effective locking policy.

Comment: @lefty This test is (as far as I can see) trying to test a lock shared by more than one instance. If each thread has it's own lock you don't need a lock at all (and threads = instances here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your example using `synchronized` is ill conceived: it is a very bad idea to synchronize on object "A". Use the following idiom instead:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

This is better because by hiding your lock from external objects, you are encapsulating your synchronization protocol and thereby implementing a safer synchronization policy.

Now, the difference between `synchronized` and `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`, is that the former is a synchronization primitive whereas the latter a higher level locking construct which provides more elaborate operations than `synchornized`.

Fore more information you may look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html and  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html in particular.

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized ("A")
```

it's not a proper usage of synchronized block. you create a different String object (in some cases) when entering this sync block, so each your thread have a different lock object and do not synchronize. Proper usage may be like

```
synchronized(this)
```

or

```
public class TaskWithSync extends Task implements Runnable {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (lock) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, you should use a single Runnable implemenation in different threads, or make your lock a static field

Comment: synchronized(this) is not considered a good practice because it does not encapsulate the synchronization policy, as other objects could "unintentionally" acquire the lock.